# Is there a mode for .conf files in AceEditor react?

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor

I need to know if there is any equivalent mode for .conf file in AceEditor for syntax highlighting.
Similar to what we have in IntelliJ, HOCON plugin.

Writing code snippet for clarity

```
import AceEditor from 'react-ace';

export function ConfigEditor({ annotations, value, onChange, markers }) {
  const mode = "something for .conf file"
  return (
    <div className="editor">
      <AceEditor
        className="editor__ace-editor"
        mode={mode}
        theme="chrome"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        annotations={annotations}
        enableBasicAutocompletion
        enableLiveAutocompletion
        showPrintMargin={false}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true, enableSnippets: true }}
        markers={markers}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

I found out the modes supported for the editor here: https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/blob/master/docs/Modes.md
but seems there is no supported one for .conf file

Comment: Is ini syntax close enough to the version of conf syntax you are looking for?

Comment: I believe it is more and less the same format. What is the mode for .ini file?

Comment: it is ace/mode/ini

Comment: It seems this mode would not work for the .conf file I have. Thanks @auser for the suggestion though

Comment: Try creating feature request on ace repository, showing the file for which that mode doesn't work.